# How to tell other threads that the task corresponding to this record (in DB) was taken by me?

Tags: java, database, multithreading

Right now, I am thinking of implementing multi-threading to take tasks corresponding to records in the DB tables. The tasks will be ordered by created date. Now, I am stuck to handle the case that when one task (record) being taken, other tasks should skip this one and chase the next one. 
Is there any way to do this? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Mark the task as in-progress in the database?

Comment: I can add a status column for sure. but what will happen, if thread 1 gets it, and thread 2 try to get it before thread 1 update the status from pending to in-progress? I understand thread 2 will fail to get it if I use some kind of lock (next question will be which lock I should use for mysql). However, thread 2 will be blocked instead of going to chase next one. Am I right?

Comment: That's what database transactions are for, or perhaps, depending on how complicated this is, a dedicated scheduler.

Comment: @chrylis, I get confused. Let us see if thread 1 and 2 run select to get record A task at the same time and thread 1 got it. After thread 1 finished, will thread 2 directly take record A or it will run the select again to check which one is the next qualified record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to make a synchronized `pickATask()` method and free threads can only pick a task by this method. 
this will force the other free threads to wait for their order.

```
synchronized public NeedTask pickATask(){

return task;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to how big is your data insertion you can either use global vectorized variables or use a table in the database itself to record values like (string TASK, boolean Taken, boolean finished, int Owner_PID).
By using the database to check the status you tend to accomplish a faster code in large scale, but if do not have too many threads or this code will run just once the (Synchronized)  global variable approach may be a better solution.

Comment: Alex, there is nothing needs to be inserted in my concerns. Other part will insert the record to the task table. My concern is when multiple threads try to take the task from the table, how can I make sure only one record being taken by one thread. Other threads will skip it.

Comment: You can add a column with a boolean value into that table that the threads can check before start the task, mark when begin them and if needed to do the task again latter, mark as free at the end of the thread or some event.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion if you create multiple thread to read from db and every thread involve in I/O operation and some kind of serialization while reading row from same table.In my mind this is not scallable and also some performance impact.

My solution will be one thread will be producer which will read the row in batch and create task and submit the task to execution (will be thread pool of worker to do the actual task.)Now we have two module which can be scallable independently.In producer side if required we can create multiple thread and every thread will read some partition data.For an example Thread 1 will read 0-100 and thread 2 read 101-200.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you manage your communication between java and DB. Are you using direct jdbc calls, Hibernate, Spring Data or any other ORM framework. In case you use just JDBC you can manage this whole issue on your DB level. you will need to configure your DB to lock your record upon writing. I.e. once a record was selected for update no-one can read it until the update is finished.
In case that you use some ORM framework (Such as Hibernate for example) the framework allows you to manage concurrency issues. See about Optimistic and Pessimistic locking. Pessimistic locking does approximately what is described above - Once the record is being updated no-one can read it until the update is finished. Optimistic one uses versioning mechanism, and then multiple threads can try to update the record but only the first one succeeds and the rest will get an exception saying that they are now working with stale data and they should read the record again. The versioning mechanism is to add a version column that is usually a number or sometimes timestamp. Each thread reads the record and upon update it checks if the version in DB still the same. If so it means no-ne else updated the record and upon update the version is changed (incremented or current timestamp is set). If the version changed then someone else already updated the record since it was read and so this thread has stale record and should not be allowed to update it. Optimistic locking shows better performance in environment where reading heavily outnumbers writing